# Running a script 24/7

Tags: python, web, cgi

I am tyring to find a solution for running a python script of mine 24/7.

Research led me to the conclusion that I probably need a CGI hosting.
But suppose that I have one (and which type of hosts should I look for?) :
how will I make the script run all the time?

In pseudo-code it should be something like this:

```
if (time_since_last_run(script.py)>100):
     run(script.py)
```

Please give me a direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CGI has nothing to do with running a script continuously. Also your problem seems to be to run your script on a regular schedule. Depending on your operating system, you can look into Scheduled Tasks on Windows (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596) or cron on other systems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

You still need a computer that runs continuously, either at home or with some hosting enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use supervisord (http://supervisord.org/)

Answer (score 0):

CGI is used for creating websites with e.g. forms, but not for scripts which run in 24/7 and do tasks A,B, etc.

You need a physical PC, dedicated server or at least a virtual machine.

Unlike Linux, which is widely used today, Unix is a less popular operating system. Servers operating 24 x 7 primarily use Unix operating systems.

A unix server is one of the cheapest way for your solution.